# Regex/grep to pull dot path out of string

Tags: regex, grep

Given the following string which may appear any number of times across various documents and in various different formats, I want to pull out the part between the quotes. I Only want strings which meet the following conditions.  Starts and ends with " (between two quotes) and has 1 or more dots (.) within the string.

@CheckWith(value = PasswordCheck.class, message = "validation.password.blah.foo")

The following regex gives me the first three parts of the string validation.password.blah but misses the .foo

```
(\")([a-zA-Z]{1,}\.{1}){1,}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
"([a-zA-Z]{1,}\.[a-zA-Z.]{1,})"
```

Note that instead of `{1,}` you can usually use `+`, but I'm not sure if grep supports that without an extended option.

Explanation:

```
"                  # match a literal '"' character
(                  # start capture group
  [a-zA-Z]{1,}       # one or more letters
  \.                 # match a literal '.' character
  [a-zA-Z.]{1,}      # one or more letters or '.' characters
)                  # end capture group
"                  # match a literal '"' character
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the regex you are looking for is this: `"[a-zA-Z]+(\.[a-zA-Z]+)+`

You should have in mind that it wont include last `"` and will only accept letters between the dots.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `egrep` (or `grep -E`), you can use

```
"([a-zA_Z]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]+"
```

(quotes are part of the regex, escape if needed).